# TTreeViewItem in-place editor using styles

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi 10.4.2, I am adding an in-place editor for the text property of a custom `TreeViewItem` of a `TTreeView` in FMX, similar to the way the VCL version works. After failing to accomplish this in simple code, I decided to try my hand at accomplishing it using FMX Styles. Below is the code for my test project, along with the text of the `StyleBook`.

This is my first attempt at working with styles and it appears to work the way I expected it to in Windows. But I was wondering if this is the correct way to use styles, or am I missing something and/or using the styles feature wrong in some way?

Added...Or maybe a better question would be Is this the best way to access the "editor" object I added to the default TTreeViewItem style?

Note: For the style, I used the "Edit Custom Style" option for a `TTreeViewItems`, and simply added a `TEdit` to it and made it invisible by default. When you double click a node, the logic makes the `TEdit` visible and sets it text property to that of the Node. When you change the `TEdit` text and press Return, the `TEdit` is set to invisible again and the `TEdit` text is copied to the node text property. I  plan on using this same component for Android and Apple versions of my program, but have not tested or worked on that yet. My assumption is that I will need to add the platforms to the `StyleBook` for the `TreeViewItem`, but the basic logic should work the same as Windows.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.UITypes, FMX.Forms, FMX.TreeView, FMX.Controls, FMX.Edit, FMX.Types,
  FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

type
  TVLinkTreeViewItem = class(TTreeViewItem)
  private
    fData: string;
    procedure TreeViewItem1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditorExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditorKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
  public
    property Data: string read fData write fData;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, c: Integer;
  vNode1,
  vNode2: TVLinkTreeViewItem;
begin
  TreeView1.BeginUpdate;
  TreeView1.Clear;
  for I := 0 to 4 do
    begin
      vNode1 := TVLinkTreeViewItem.Create(TreeView1);
      vNode1.Text := 'Level 1 - '+ IntToStr(I);
      vNode1.Data := vNode1.Name;
      TreeView1.AddObject(vNode1);
      for c := 0 to 4 do
        begin
          vNode2 := TVLinkTreeViewItem.Create(vNode1);
          vNode2.Text := 'Level 2 - '+ IntToStr(c);
          vNode2.Data := vNode2.Name;
          vNode1.AddObject(vNode2);
        end;
    end;
  TreeView1.ExpandAll;
  treeView1.EndUpdate;
end;

{ TVLinkTreeViewItem }

constructor TVLinkTreeViewItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  self.StyleLookup := 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyle';
  self.ApplyStyleLookup;
  fData := '';
end;

procedure TVLinkTreeViewItem.ApplyStyle;
var
  vEditor: TEdit;
begin
  inherited;
  //need to get Editor each time needed. Not sure why,
  //but doesn't work when trying to set a component variable called fEditor here,
  //then have the OnXXXX routines use fEditor, instead of finding the editor themselves
  vEditor:= FindStyleResource('Editor') as TEdit;
  if Assigned(vEditor) then
    begin
      vEditor.OnKeyDown := EditorKeyUp;
      OnDblClick := TreeViewItem1DblClick;
      vEditor.OnExit := EditorExit;
    end;
end;

procedure TVLinkTreeViewItem.TreeViewItem1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vEditor: TEdit;
begin
  //need to get Editor each time needed. Not sure why,
  //but doesn't work when trying to set a component variable called fEditor in ApplyStyle.
  vEditor:= FindStyleResource('Editor') as TEdit;
  if assigned(vEditor) then
    begin
      vEditor.Visible := true;
      vEditor.Text := Text;
      vEditor.SetFocus;
      vEditor.SelectAll;
    end;
end;

procedure TVLinkTreeViewItem.EditorKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  vEditor: TEdit;
begin
  inherited;
  //need to get Editor each time needed. Not sure why,
  //but doesn't work when trying to set a component variable called fEditor in ApplyStyle.
  vEditor:= FindStyleResource('Editor') as TEdit;
  if not assigned(vEditor) then
    exit;
  if Key = vkReturn then
    begin
      Text := vEditor.Text;
      vEditor.Visible := false;
    end
  else if Key in [vkEscape, vkCancel, vkTab, vkHardwareBack] then
    begin
      vEditor.Visible := false;
    end;
end;

procedure TVLinkTreeViewItem.EditorExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  vEditor: TEdit;
begin
  //need to get Editor each time needed. Not sure why,
  //but doesn't work when trying to set a component variable called fEditor in ApplyStyle.
  vEditor:= FindStyleResource('Editor') as TEdit;
  if Assigned(vEditor) then
    vEditor.Visible := false;
end;

end.
```

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 500
  ClientWidth = 640
  StyleBook = StyleBook1
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnShow = FormShow
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object TreeView1: TTreeView
    Align = Left
    Size.Width = 269.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 500.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Viewport.Width = 265.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 496.000000000000000000
  end
  object StyleBook1: TStyleBook
    Styles = <
      item
      end
      item
        Platform = 'Windows 10 Desktop'
        ResourcesBin = {
          464D585F5354594C4520322E35010616564C696E6B5472656556696577497465
          6D5374796C650395050631564C696E6B54726565566965774974656D5374796C
          657472656576696577657870616E646572627574746F6E7374796C6503E10306
          23564C696E6B54726565566965774974656D5374796C65436865636B426F7853
          74796C6503E40B005450463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D6506
          16564C696E6B54726565566965774974656D5374796C6505416C69676E070643
          656E7465720A53697A652E576964746805000000000000808407400B53697A65
          2E4865696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E506C6174666F726D
          44656661756C7408085461624F726465720236000C545370656564427574746F
          6E00095374796C654E616D650606627574746F6E05416C69676E07044C656674
          0C4D617267696E732E4C6566740500000000000000C000400B4D617267696E73
          2E546F700500000000000000C000400D4D617267696E732E5269676874050000
          0000000000C000400E4D617267696E732E426F74746F6D0500000000000000C0
          00400A506F736974696F6E2E580500000000000000C000400A506F736974696F
          6E2E590500000000000000C000400A53697A652E576964746805000000000000
          00F002400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000E002401453697A65
          2E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080B5374796C654C6F6F6B7570063156
          4C696E6B54726565566965774974656D5374796C657472656576696577657870
          616E646572627574746F6E7374796C65000007544C61796F75740005416C6967
          6E0708436F6E74656E74730C4D617267696E732E4C6566740500000000000000
          A003400A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000F506400B53697A652E48
          65696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E506C6174666F726D4465
          6661756C7408000954436865636B426F7800095374796C654E616D6506056368
          65636B05416C69676E07044C6566740843616E466F637573081244697361626C
          65466F637573456666656374090A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000
          A003400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E
          506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080B5374796C654C6F6F6B75700623564C
          696E6B54726565566965774974656D5374796C65436865636B426F785374796C
          6500000654476C79706800095374796C654E616D65060A676C7970687374796C
          650C4D617267696E732E4C65667405000000000000008000400B4D617267696E
          732E546F70050000000000000080FF3F0D4D617267696E732E52696768740500
          0000000000008000400E4D617267696E732E426F74746F6D0500000000000000
          80FF3F05416C69676E07044C6566740A53697A652E5769647468050000000000
          00008003400B53697A652E48656967687405000000000000008003401453697A
          652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408000016544163746976655374796C
          65546578744F626A65637400095374796C654E616D6506047465787405416C69
          676E0706436C69656E74064C6F636B6564090A53697A652E5769647468050000
          0000000000E106400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A0034014
          53697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080454657874060454657874
          155465787453657474696E67732E576F72645772617008165465787453657474
          696E67732E486F727A416C69676E07074C656164696E670D536861646F775669
          7369626C65080D41637469766554726967676572070853656C65637465640B41
          6374697665436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B000005544564697400095374
          796C654E616D650606456469746F7219546F7563682E496E7465726163746976
          6547657374757265730B074C6F6E6754617009446F75626C655461700005416C
          69676E0706436C69656E740B5374796C654C6F6F6B7570060965646974737479
          6C65085461624F7264657202000A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000
          E106400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E
          506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C650800000000545046
          3007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D650631564C696E6B5472656556
          6965774974656D5374796C657472656576696577657870616E64657262757474
          6F6E7374796C6505416C69676E070643656E7465720B4D617267696E732E546F
          70050000000000000080FF3F0A53697A652E5769647468050000000000008084
          07400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E50
          6C6174666F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C6508085461624F726465
          720237000554506174680005416C69676E070643656E74657209446174612E50
          6174680A400000000500000000000000D36D3F431BEF4843010000001749E043
          BA09E54301000000D36D3F43C73B344401000000D36D3F431BEF484303000000
          D36D3F431BEF48430A46696C6C2E436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B064C6F
          636B6564090748697454657374080A53697A652E576964746805000000000000
          00E001400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000E001401453697A65
          2E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080B5374726F6B652E4B696E6407044E
          6F6E65000F54466C6F6174416E696D6174696F6E00084475726174696F6E0500
          0000000017B7D1F13F0C50726F70657274794E616D6506074F7061636974790A
          537461727456616C756505000000000000000000000953746F7056616C756505
          0000000000000080FF3F075472696767657206104973457870616E6465643D66
          616C73650E54726967676572496E7665727365060F4973457870616E6465643D
          747275650000000554506174680005416C69676E070643656E74657209446174
          612E506174680A400000000500000000000000CB11CF4379E93C4301000000CB
          11CF4396230A44010000007DBF1E4296230A4401000000CB11CF4379E93C4303
          000000CB11CF4379E93C430A46696C6C2E436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B
          064C6F636B656409074869745465737408074F70616369747905000000000000
          000000000A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000E001400B53697A652E
          4865696768740500000000000000E001401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44
          656661756C74080B5374726F6B652E4B696E6407044E6F6E65000F54466C6F61
          74416E696D6174696F6E00084475726174696F6E05000000000017B7D1F13F0C
          50726F70657274794E616D6506074F7061636974790A537461727456616C7565
          05000000000000000000000953746F7056616C7565050000000000000080FF3F
          0754726967676572060F4973457870616E6465643D747275650E547269676765
          72496E766572736506104973457870616E6465643D66616C7365000000005450
          463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D650623564C696E6B54726565
          566965774974656D5374796C65436865636B426F785374796C6505416C69676E
          070643656E7465720A53697A652E576964746805000000000000808407400B53
          697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A003401453697A652E506C617466
          6F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C6508085461624F72646572021200
          07544C61796F75740005416C69676E07044C6566740A53697A652E5769647468
          05000000000000009003400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000A0
          03401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408001154436865636B
          5374796C654F626A65637400095374796C654E616D65060A6261636B67726F75
          6E6405416C69676E070643656E746572074361704D6F6465070454696C65064C
          6F636B6564090C536F757263654C6F6F6B7570061B57696E646F777320313020
          4465736B746F707374796C652E706E670A53697A652E57696474680500000000
          000000D002400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000D00240145369
          7A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C740808577261704D6F646507064365
          6E7465720D416374697665547269676765720707436865636B65640A41637469
          76654C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000
          F803400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F
          75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B0044011536F75726365
          526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C650500
          000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000000000
          00B804400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB06401053
          6F75726365526563742E5269676874050000000000000082054011536F757263
          65526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C6505
          000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000000000
          0000F804400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092074010
          536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B0054011536F7572
          6365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F074000000A536F757263
          654C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000C0
          00400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F75
          726365526563742E5269676874050000000000000080034011536F7572636552
          6563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C65050000
          0000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000
          8001400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F
          75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B8034011536F75726365
          526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C650500
          0000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000000000
          00C001400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000009207401053
          6F75726365526563742E5269676874050000000000000080044011536F757263
          65526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F0740000007486F744C696E
          6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000000000008803400E53
          6F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F7572636552
          6563742E52696768740500000000000000F0034011536F75726365526563742E
          426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C6505000000000000
          00C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000C803400E
          536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365
          526563742E52696768740500000000000000B0044011536F7572636552656374
          2E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C65050000000000
          00008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000880440
          0E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F757263
          65526563742E52696768740500000000000000F0044011536F75726365526563
          742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F074000000D416374697665486F744C
          696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B40440
          0E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F757263
          65526563742E52696768740500000000000000E8044011536F75726365526563
          742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C650500000000
          000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000000000008605
          400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F7572
          6365526563742E52696768740500000000000000AC054011536F757263655265
          63742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000
          000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B4
          05400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F75
          726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000E8054011536F7572636552
          6563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F074000000B466F63757365644C
          696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000880340
          0E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F757263
          65526563742E52696768740500000000000000F0034011536F75726365526563
          742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C650500000000
          000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000C803
          400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F7572
          6365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B0044011536F757263655265
          63742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000
          000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000000000000088
          04400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F75
          726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000F0044011536F7572636552
          6563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F0740000011416374697665466F
          63757365644C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000
          000000B404400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000920640
          10536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000E8044011536F75
          726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F06400001055363616C
          650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000
          000000008605400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000DB06
          4010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000AC054011536F
          75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000EE0640000105536361
          6C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000
          0000000000B405400E536F75726365526563742E546F70050000000000000092
          074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000E805401153
          6F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000009F07400000000000
          1654427574746F6E5374796C65546578744F626A65637400095374796C654E61
          6D6506047465787405416C69676E0706436C69656E74064C6F636B6564090C4D
          617267696E732E4C6566740500000000000000C000400A53697A652E57696474
          680500000000000000F406400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000
          A003401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080D536861646F77
          56697369626C650808486F74436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B0C466F6375
          736564436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B0B4E6F726D616C436F6C6F720708
          636C61426C61636B0C50726573736564436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B00
          0000}
      end>
    Left = 116
    Top = 150
  end
end
```

```
object TStyleContainer
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyle'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 265.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 52
    object TSpeedButton
      StyleName = 'button'
      Align = Left
      Margins.Left = 3.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 3.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 3.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 3.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 3.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 3.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 15.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 14.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyletreeviewexpanderbuttonstyle'
    end
    object TLayout
      Align = Contents
      Margins.Left = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 245.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object TCheckBox
        StyleName = 'check'
        Align = Left
        CanFocus = False
        DisableFocusEffect = True
        Size.Width = 20.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        StyleLookup = 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyleCheckBoxStyle'
      end
      object TGlyph
        StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
        Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
        Margins.Top = 1.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
        Margins.Bottom = 1.000000000000000000
        Align = Left
        Size.Width = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
      end
      object TActiveStyleTextObject
        StyleName = 'text'
        Align = Client
        Locked = True
        Size.Width = 225.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Text = 'Text'
        TextSettings.WordWrap = False
        TextSettings.HorzAlign = Leading
        ShadowVisible = False
        ActiveTrigger = Selected
        ActiveColor = claBlack
      end
      object TEdit
        StyleName = 'Editor'
        Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
        Align = Client
        StyleLookup = 'editstyle'
        TabOrder = 0
        Size.Width = 225.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Visible = False
      end
    end
  end
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyletreeviewexpanderbuttonstyle'
    Align = Center
    Margins.Top = 1.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 265.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 54
    object TPath
      Align = Center
      Data.Path = {
        0500000000000000D36D3F431BEF4843010000001749E043BA09E54301000000
        D36D3F43C73B344401000000D36D3F431BEF484303000000D36D3F431BEF4843}
      Fill.Color = claBlack
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 7.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 7.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Kind = None
      object TFloatAnimation
        Duration = 0.000099999997473788
        PropertyName = 'Opacity'
        StartValue = 0.000000000000000000
        StopValue = 1.000000000000000000
        Trigger = 'IsExpanded=false'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsExpanded=true'
      end
    end
    object TPath
      Align = Center
      Data.Path = {
        0500000000000000CB11CF4379E93C4301000000CB11CF4396230A4401000000
        7DBF1E4296230A4401000000CB11CF4379E93C4303000000CB11CF4379E93C43}
      Fill.Color = claBlack
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Opacity = 0.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 7.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 7.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Kind = None
      object TFloatAnimation
        Duration = 0.000099999997473788
        PropertyName = 'Opacity'
        StartValue = 0.000000000000000000
        StopValue = 1.000000000000000000
        Trigger = 'IsExpanded=true'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsExpanded=false'
      end
    end
  end
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'VLinkTreeViewItemStyleCheckBoxStyle'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 265.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 18
    object TLayout
      Align = Left
      Size.Width = 18.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object TCheckStyleObject
        StyleName = 'background'
        Align = Center
        CapMode = Tile
        Locked = True
        SourceLookup = 'Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png'
        Size.Width = 13.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 13.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        WrapMode = Center
        ActiveTrigger = Checked
        ActiveLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 31.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 44.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 46.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 65.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 62.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 88.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
        SourceLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 3.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 16.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 23.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 6.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 32.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
        HotLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 17.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 30.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 25.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 44.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 34.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 60.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
        ActiveHotLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 45.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 58.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 67.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 86.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 116.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
        FocusedLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 17.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 30.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 25.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 44.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 34.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 60.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
        ActiveFocusedLink = <
          item
            SourceRect.Left = 45.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 146.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 58.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 159.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 1.500000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 67.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 219.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 86.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 238.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 116.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 318.000000000000000000
          end>
      end
    end
    object TButtonStyleTextObject
      StyleName = 'text'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      Margins.Left = 3.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 244.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      ShadowVisible = False
      HotColor = claBlack
      FocusedColor = claBlack
      NormalColor = claBlack
      PressedColor = claBlack
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Wrong output? Crashes? 
 Something else? Please read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), 
 take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
 read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), 
 as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The second paragraph asks the question. As stated, the code appears to work, but I was wondering if I am using styles correctly?

Comment: So this is more a post for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (Another site part of StackExchange).